# Septic line drop requirements - 100' too long of a run?

Tags: septic

I'm installing a modular building on a piece of land I've purchased. The land is only 60' wide with trees lining the sides. For me to set the modular building and still have the ability to get around the building, I'll need to locate the bathroom approximately 95' from the septic tank (septic is already in place). The minimum height of the floor bottom is 18" from ground (ground is rather level). The building is 36' long and the run would start in the northwest corner (where the bathroom is located) and run to the southeat corner as the septic is located off to the southeast at almost a 45 degree angle. I'm trying to figure If I'll be able to make that distance work and still have enough drop and not have the pipe sticking out of the ground. I know the line should drop 1-4"/foot, but I'm not sure if 100'is just too long of a run. Anyone have experience running a drop that long from say a mobile home?

Comment: If you could add a diagram or plot plan I’m certain your question would get better answers.  I read twice trying to visualize your property and setup and it’s very hard to “see” based on your description.  You’re asking for free help, and most people will simply pass rather than take out pen and paper and try to draw what you describe.

Comment: Wow that is a long run you may need to consider a sewage pit and pump to get the waste to the septic tank. Small tank and transfer pumps are not very expensive and would solve the distance problem.